# How to fetch last inserted 2 rows of perticular id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am using mysql. I am facing problem in fetching the rows. my table is like this.

```
vehicleno     lat       lng       status        rdate       rtime
  12
  13
  12                                                        05:56:45
  12                                                        05:58:45
```

This table keeps on inserting value for tracking the vehicle. I want lastly inserted 2 values(rows) of perticular vehicle(eg. 12). So that I can identify weather vehicle is idle or moving. How can I write a query. Please help me in this.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE vehicleno=12 ORDER BY rtime DESC limit 2` should do the trick. Without knowing what column type `rtime` is I can't be sure.

Comment: Glad it worked. Without data to work with I'm unsure how to get the SQL to work for all vehicles.

Comment: I don't know what hibernate is mate, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change rtime column datatype time to datetime

MYSQL

```
    SELECT vehicleno, lat, lng, rtime
    FROM vehicle where vehicleno=12
    ORDER BY rtime DESC LIMIT 2
```

Edited

```
   hql2.setMaxResults(2);
```

Comment: here FROM vehicle where vehicleno=12

Comment: Yes , Here it is, `String hql2="SELECT rtime FROM HistoryLatitudeBean WHERE vehicleno=:vehicleno ORDER BY rtime DESC limit 2";`

Comment: query is executing but its not limiting for 2.

Comment: And remove LIMIT 2 from query and use instead setMaxResults given in post

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, it will work for Hibernate.

SELECT top 2 rtime FROM HistoryLatitudeBean WHERE vehicleno=:vehicleno ORDER BY rtime DESC